# Figura grande atrapalha o posicionamento das outras

Tags: latex

Em um relatório em Latex que estou escrevendo, estou tentando inserir uma figura grande no começo do capítulo. É um fluxograma do tamanho de uma página:

```tex
\begin{figure}[!htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{visio/fluxograma} % fluxograma é um PDF
  \caption{Fluxograma descrevendo a metodologia.}
  \label{fig:methodology}
\end{figure}
```

O que está acontecendo é que, por ser do tamanho de uma página, o Latex está postergando a inserção da figura para o final do capítulo, após o texto. Como o fluxograma só é inserido no fim, ele atrapalha a inserção das outras figuras que estão no meio do capítulo. Daí, as figuras ficam todas no final do capítulo.

**Pergunta** 
Como faço para inserir o fluxograma na posição correta?

Tentei colocar os atributos `[!htb]` no fluxograma, mas não adiantou. Modificando o tamanho para 80% eu consegui, mas eu queria mantê-lo com o tamanho da página.

Comment: Só pra constar, há um outro Q&A do grupo Stack Exchange específico para questões sobre Tex/Latex (em inglês): http://tex.stackexchange.com/ Não que eu ache que a sua pergunta não caiba aqui, mas apenas pra você saber que existe (pois pode te ajudar no futuro em outras questões). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No [link que o @Luiz Vieira indicou](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat), havia o parâmetro `p` que eu ainda não havia testado. Ele especifica para a figura que ela pode ser posicionada em uma página ou uma coluna. Bastou eu acrescentar esse parâmetro que funcionou sem problemas:

```tex
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{visio/fluxograma} % fluxograma é um PDF
  \caption{Fluxograma descrevendo a metodologia.}
  \label{fig:methodology}
\end{figure}
```

Um único caracter resolvia :)

Answer (score 3):

Figuras e tabelas são elementos flutuantes (*floating*), e por isso o Latex se encarrega de escolher o melhor lugar para colocá-los de acordo com o espaço disponível e o tamanho do elemento.

Uma alternativa que pode funcionar pra você é não usar a tag `\begin{figure}` e trocá-la por um elemento genérico centralizado `\begin{center}`. Experimente fazer assim:

```tex
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}

\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{visio/fluxograma} % fluxograma é um PDF
    \captionof{figure}{Fluxograma descrevendo a metodologia.}
    \label{fig:methodology}
\end{center}
```

EDIT: Inclui o uso do pacote `caption` (que é necessário para o uso de `\captionof`)

Comment: Acabei de achar essa pergunta do Tex(en) que também pode ser útil pra você: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat A resposta aceita tem toda uma explicação sobre como funciona o algoritmo de flutuação de elementos e a segunda resposta é na linha da que eu ofereci aqui.

Comment: Oi Luiz, dei uma olhada na página que você me indicou. Você nem vai acreditar, mas só de incluir o argumento `p` (para páginas) resolveu meu problema. Ficou assim `\begin{figure}[!htbp]`. Você pode incluir isso na sua resposta também?

Comment: @VictorHugo Que massa que funcionou então! Eu poderia facilmente incluir na minha resposta, mas não acho que é condizente porque é outro tipo de solução/sugestão. Por que você não adiciona uma resposta descrevendo a sua própria solução? Acho que fica melhor. :)

Comment: Beleza, Luiz Vieira. Acrescentei a resposta. Obrigado! :)